# Filter an XML file

Tags: php, xml, json, xpath

I'm attempting to use a form to filter an XML file and am having toruble using xpath to get the desired results.

```
<?php
$filterHeading = 'CD';
$filterText = '1989';

$filename = "xml/xml_cd.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

echo 

$result = $xml->xpath('//' + $filterHeading + '[YEAR="' + $filterText + '"]');

print_r($result);


?>
```

My aim is to use this PHP script to eventually take the variables (heading/text) from the webpage and display in JSON format. However I am unable to get the XML filter itself to work - any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

XML

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the XML you're trying to parse?

Comment: Added as na edit - thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node `YEAR` itself isn't equal to `1989`, the text in it is. So

```
//CD[YEAR/text()="1989"]
```

will do the trick. In your code:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//'.$filterHeading.'[YEAR/text()="'.$filterText.'"]');
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in H:\University\Year 3\Web\XAMMP\xampp-portable\htdocs\Assignment\filter.php on line 12
ArrayArray ( )

I keep getting this error message no matter what way I try to do it. (New to PHP here) If possible I would also like to maintain the use of the variables to expand later

Comment: After digging up old memories, concatenation is done with a `.` in PHP... Try updated answer.

Comment: Again, thank you for the swift response!

I get the same error again on the same line as before. The "$result =.." I can't seem to spot why!

Comment: Tried to recreate it without the file: http://pastebin.com/GmquXEuN, it seems to work... You should try to check if `simplexml_load_file` is giving you the expected output (same as `SimpleXMLElement`). Let me know!

Comment: Confirmed that simplexml_load_file($filename) is working as intedned with a if == FALSE statement. [EDIT]Also prints fine (sorry brain meltdown!)

Comment: Well learning PHP etc for 9 hours does this to you. MY XML file did not contain a year that was equal to 1989..

I cannot explain how grateful I am .. Or how silly I feel!

Thank you Robin.

Comment: Yep, I did change that in the pastebin file... You're welcome, good luck with php.